# Post media entity documents to Drupal 8 via REST API

Tags: rest, drupal

We are looking for a way to quickly post documents (pdfs) to a drupal 8.5.1 site via REST API module as media entity objects - the metadata associated with the post would need to include not just the name and description of the document but also the taxonomy term that the document belongs to.

For example, given a file in the current directory named "sample.pdf" (with a title "Sample Document"), the curl POST might look something like this (and sadly I am omitting anything to indicate the taxonomy term associated with the document):

```
curl --include \
  --request POST \
  --user <use>:<pass> \
  --header 'Content-type: application/hal+json' \
  --data-binary '@sample.pdf' \
  http://<domain>/entity/node?_format=hal_json
```

Does anyone have any experience / example code to point us in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

[Apache Tika](https://tika.apache.org/) is a great tool for extracting data from different file types.

You may want to extract metadata before posting the file, in this case you can make a script that takes your pdf and either posts :

- JSON data to use with REST API
- form-data to use with FORM API (use the curl option `--form` and change the url to match the appropriate entity form submit handler).

Or you can post the file content as a whole, then hook into Drupal entity save process to extract text and metadata from the content stream and alter the entity accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Since 8.6.x, You can use Rest API with the ressource FileUpload to upload your file, have a look here https://www.drupal.org/node/2941420

Once uploaded, you will get a file id to use with the endpoint entity/media (post) in your field.